# Array to html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have data in Array format as below... (sample one) this is an array..Based on data , I need to generate a html table by custom condition... say, table header will be day1,2,3,4,5,6 and below array has to be based for each header to add row based on the conditions... I have given the details for reference

```
 var array=   [{"day":1,"summary":"proge1"},
    {"day":1,"summary":"proge2"},
    {"day":1,"summary":"proge3"},
    {"day":2,"summary":"Tues1"},
    {"day":2,"summary":"Tues2"},
    {"day":2,"summary":"Tues3"},
    {"day":3,"summary":"Wed1"},
    {"day":3,"summary":"Wed2"},
    {"day":3,"summary":"Wed3 "},
    {"day":4,"summary":"Thur1"},
    {"day":4,"summary":"Thur2"},
    {"day":5,"summary":"Fri1"},
    {"day":6,"summary":"Sat1"}]
```

I want to generate a html table based on this data such that it should display as below..can someone please suggest me how to accomplish this..

```
    <table>
     <tr>
                       <td align="center">Day1</td>
                        <td align="center">Day2</td>
                        <td align="center">Day3</td>
                        <td align="center">Day4</td>
                        <td align="center">Day5</td>
                        <td align="center"> Day6 </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

output:

```
    ----------------------------------------------
    Day1    |Day2   Day3    Day4    Day5    Day6
   -----------------------------------------------
    proge1  Tue1    Wed1    Thur1   Fri1    Sat1

    proge2  Tue2    Wed2    Thur2       
    proge3  Tue3    Wed3
```

Is that we need to call function (day) for each td and generate table by the values?

Comment: I'd suggest post what you have tried so far, so we can continue on what you have.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to have arrays with unique values:

```
var  newarray=[];
 array.forEach(function(el){
   for(var depth=0;depth<newarray.length;depth++){
       newarray[pos]=newarray[pos]||[];
       if(!newarray[pos][el.day-1]){//if the day isnt filled, day 1 is at position zero ( thats why -1)
          newarray[pos][el.day-1]=el;
          return;
       }
  }
});
```

This will create a table like structure:

```
newarray=[
   [{day:1 ...},{day:2}]
   [{day:1}]
];
```

Now you can loop trough and build your table:

```
table=newarray.map(function(row){
  var newrow="<tr>";
  newrow+=row.map(function(el){
        return "<td>"+el.summary+"</td>";
  }).join("");
 newrow+="</tr>";
 return newrow;
}).join("");//make string
```

Then append it to your dom:

```
 document.body.innerHTML=table;
```

Comment: Hi Jonas w ... sorry am not getting it.... where are we passing the array.... to get new array[] here.... could you please be more specific... sorry if am missing somethign here

Comment: array.forEach ... loops over your original array and creates a new one, newarray. Than i build a html string out of it, its name is table.